# text document shows random characters

Tags: text-editor

I had a text document notepad file in my windows7 with some text written in it then I wrote some more text in ubuntu in that file but now it seems that I have lost all the texts since it shows random characters mostly like /00/00/00/ do you have any idea how I can recover my information again?tnx

Comment: This can sometimes happen if the page coding is set to different settings. I'll look around and see if I can find an answer.

Comment: Can you tell me the text editor you are using in Ubuntu, please.

Comment: I used Emacs23 but it was no use it still shows mainly /00/00

Comment: Can you try to open the file with gedit, vi or another text editor? Just to see if the same thing happens.

Comment: it's still the same result :(

Answer (score 0):

You see random characters when trying to read the text document back in Microsoft's Notepad, right?

Did you trying reading it back from Ubuntu? (if this works, then it's probably Notepad's fault) If you can't check from Ubuntu, try installing [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/) in Windows, and reading your text document with it.

As a general rule, I would recommend avoiding Microsoft's Notepad in Windows, and using a more serious alternative, [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) or Notepad++ for instance. (Notepad2 is easier to get into, but replaces Microsoft's Notepad in Windows' menus) It will save you from a lot of pain when being in non Windows-only environments.

Comment: I can't read it even from ubuntu and I have notepad++ but it still shows /00/00/ ...

Comment: Could you give us a link to a copy of the document? (if it doesn't contain anything private)